# Batch script: Merging multiple idx files with vobsubmux

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to merge x many files to one file with a program.
Program works like this:

vobsubmux.exe sub1.idx sub2.idx sub3.idx ... etc

Now, I have those files in a directory, how can I make a batch pick them all and merge with vobsubmux.exe with a batch script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.idx) do call set idx=%%idx%% "%%a"
vobsubmux %idx%
```